# Acer Chromebook spin 511 corrupted bios cant flash

Tags: bios, chromebook

i have a spin 511 that somehow got its bios corrupt beacuse i was trying to bypass it but failed,is there a way to fix it without buying more tools? I tryed to flash the ChromeOS made for it but it says that the storage device doesn't have ChromeOS on it. Right now it only shows the ChromeOS is Missing or damaged screen.

Comment: If no one here can help you can probably find an answer on this subreddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/chrultrabook/